Почему openvpn-client не подключается в windows?
Установлен openvpn server в ubuntu. Все ок :
~$ sudo netstat -tulpn |grep openvpn
udp        0      0 192.168.8.4:443         0.0.0.0:*                           676/openvpn

Сначала установил клиента тоже в linux: все ок, тоннель есть, ping между сервером и клиентом ок.
Удалил клиента в linux и перенес все конфиги клиента в windows. Не подключается - ошибок в логах и журнале нет(желтая иконка с замком).
netstat -a порта 443 не слушает.
Открыл 443 порт (входящие-исходящие) скрины:
[вход-исход][1][![вход-исход][2]][2][![введите сюда описание изображения][3]][3]
Пробросил порты на роутере:
[![роутер][4]][4]
Все тоже -443 порт не слушается
При установке приложения Open VPN GUI созданы 2 сетевых адаптера : tap-windows6 и wintun.
В настройках ругаются- кабель не подк :
[![настройки][5]][5]
При этом в свойствах все ок:
[![свойства][6]][6]
Чего посоветуете?
В параметрах отображается только 1 адаптер:[!адаптер][7]][7]
server.conf:
local 192.168.8.4
port 443
proto udp
dev tun
ca keys/ca.crt
cert keys/server.crt
key keys/server.key
dh keys/dh.pem
tls-auth keys/ta.key 0
server 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
max-clients 32
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
log-append /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
verb 4
mute 20
daemon
mode server
tls-server
comp-lzo
tun-mtu 1500
mssfix 1620
cipher AES-256-GCM```
 
client.conf:

resolv-retry infinite
nobind
remote 192.168.8.4 443
proto udp
dev tun
#windows-driver tap-windows6
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
tls-client
tls-auth ta.key 1
float
keepalive 10 120
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 0
cipher AES-256-GCM
remote-cert-tls server
tun-mtu 1500```

  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/0O9mGnCY.png
  [2]: https://i.sstatic.net/ojxLoIA4.png
  [3]: https://i.sstatic.net/pB6li6tf.png
  [4]: https://i.sstatic.net/2fJ0dYIM.png
  [5]: https://i.sstatic.net/lygjC89F.png
  [6]: https://i.sstatic.net/pBwnrjCf.png
  [7]: https://i.sstatic.net/9kx8B3KN.png


сервер : enp3s0: inet 192.168.8.4/24,  tun0: inet 172.16.10.1 peer 172.16.10.2/32 scope global tun0 , клиент: IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.8.105 . Пытаюсь подключиться по протоколу udp , порт 443

Про роутер, и ping - от безысходности(

server.conf:  local 192.168.8.4
port 443
proto udp
dev tun
ca keys/ca.crt
cert keys/server.crt
key keys/server.key
dh keys/dh.pem
tls-auth keys/ta.key 0
server 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
max-clients 32
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
log-append /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
verb 4
mute 20
daemon
mode server
tls-server
comp-lzo
tun-mtu 1500
mssfix 1620
cipher AES-256-GCM

client.conf: client
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
remote 192.168.8.4 443
proto udp
dev tun
#windows-driver tap-windows6
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
tls-client
tls-auth ta.key 1
float
keepalive 10 120
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 0
cipher AES-256-GCM
remote-cert-tls server
tun-mtu 1500

а если пути, которые непонятно куда в винде исправить на как положено. Я например указываю у себя так  ca c:\openVPN\keys\ca.crt
cert c:\openVPN\keys\win10.crt
key c:\openVPN\keys\win10.key

пробовал указать абсолютный путь к серт в файле client.conf: ругается : Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in client.conf.ovpn:8: ca (2.6.12) . Принимает ток относительный путь почему то

четко  указано два бакслэша и диск? Именно бакслэшь, а не слэш

Похоже все-таки ограничения провайдера. Как сообщили в поддержке - Роском(надзор кажется) для всех провайдеров указивка- ввести ограничения на соединения openvpn(

да слеши нарисовал как в примере,  и диск, и большую 'C' и 'c' пробовал
